# Multiple record "Copy" doesn't work for a subtype

Tags: multi-record

The functionality "Copy" a multiple record work properly if a "Custom Field Set" is defined for a Type (Contact, Organization, Individual). I mean, that after "Copy" a record the new record will be created and includes the original record data.
But if a "Custom Field Set" is defined for a Sub-Type, e.g. Individual/Student, then the "Copy" creates the new record, BUT WITHOUT copying the original record data. I need to use multiple records to update previous record just in one field and I don't want to retype all data I have already input before, and I need to track the history of records.
Thank to anybody who can help me.